# Linking multiple objects to a master object with different color faces? {beginner}

Tags: materials

Blender noob here.
I Built a rough cube house and duplicated 10s of them, how do I change the roof color/material of the house (master) and change all of the duplicates to have the same color/material roof at the same time?

[image]

Comment: SOLVED IT! I selected all the uncolored houses and the colored one last, then I pressed control+L and clicked object data. Thank God!

Comment: Hello and welcome. You should post that as an answer bellow instead, with a short description of the procedure, so it may help others in the future

Comment: Agree, because now I am a person in the future who could use this answer :P